# finding rar in yaourt

Tags: arch-linux, output, yaourt, rar

I try to install rar using yaourt, problem is I get +5k results and can't filter out the package containing rar. Neither `|grep` helps nor `|head`, the first hundreds of lines are lib'rar'ies.

What could I do to get around this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You use an AUR helper that actually works and is not [fundamentally insecure](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/AUR_helpers#Comparison_table):

```
cower -s '^rar$'
aur/rar 5.3.0-1 (668, 6.91)
    A command-line port of the rar compression utility
```

Answer (score 0):

You can search by "Exact Name" on the AUR website: https://aur.archlinux.org/packages/?O=0&SeB=N&K=rar&outdated=&SB=n&SO=a&PP=50&do_Search=Go which brings you to https://aur.archlinux.org/packages/rar/.

Answer (score 0):

Take some words of the description from this link: https://aur.archlinux.org/packages/rar/

The description is :

> A command-line port of the rar compression utility

for example use:

```
yaourt rar compression utility
```